# I want ideas for a (Data Leak Prevention) project

Tags: c#

I have a project in college about (DLP - Data Leak Prevention)
and we have to pick up ideas under this title.

do you have any suggestions for me ? ? ?

one my friends suggested building a DLP application that prevents stealing a projects' source code from a network of computers.

What do you think of that idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preventing active stealing is very hard. Since hiding data is easy. Encryption, packing, password protected archives, obfuscation, steganography,...

To prevent all that you'd need to lock down the computer very much, and only allow trusted code to run. But then programming on that computer won't be possible either. Since programming introduces new code by definition.

The best you can achieve in practice without too many restrictions on the user is preventing accidental leaks.

Comment: what do you think about monitoring transfers over the network to prevent any source code transfer, maybe over HTTP or FTP ?

Comment: As I said, you won't pick it up if the user obfuscates or encrypts the data. Monitoring TCP connections for forbidden data fragments should be possible. I don't know if there is a usermode API for that though. Perhaps you need a supporting kernel mode driver, which as far as I know can't be written in C# on windows. But I heard of some usermode firewall APIs, so perhaps you're lucky.

Comment: You could also inject a dll into all applications that hooks some APIs. But you shouldn't do that in C# either.